# Wrapping a foreign pointer into a SWIG data structure

Tags: lua, swig

I'm using Lua with two C libraries, one of which is using SWIG and one is wrapped manually.

The library which is wrapped manually is an interface to Freetype; it creates `FT_Face` pointers in C which it returns as lightuserdata.

Now I need to pass this `FT_Face` as a parameter to one of the functions which is wrapped by SWIG. However, SWIG of course does not take ordinary userdata as parameters, but expects that every C pointer is created by SWIG - even though I have a `FT_Face` pointer, SWIG  wants to see a `SWIGTYPE_p_FT_Face`, which is `swig_lua_userdata` underneath.

Is there a way to turn Lua userdata into `swig_lua_userdata`? How does I get SWIG to 'recognise' my `FT_Face` userdata as a valid parameter to a function?

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be "typemaps":

```
%typemap(in) FT_Face {
   $1 = (FT_Face)lua_touserdata(L,$input);
}
%typemap(typecheck) FT_Face = void*;
```